# Trigger a click on LinkButton

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to trigger a click on LinkButton Home when `#newHome` is clicked
I have the trigger function below but it does not seem to be working as follows :

```
<li id="newHome"><a href="#" style="font-size: 1.05em;">Home</a></li>

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_Home" class="menuLink" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton_Home_Click"><div class="menuIcon">Home</div></asp:LinkButton>

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#newHome').click(function (e) {
            $('#' + '<%=LinkButton_Home.ClientID%>').trigger('click');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem a bit more precisely than “does not seem to be working”? Any errors in the console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console. Clicking it will just trigger # 
As if there is no trigger click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference()

In order to simulate the postback event for asp.net control you could use Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference() to raise that event directly.

```
<li id="newHome"><a href="#" style="font-size: 1.05em;">Home</a></li>

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_Home" class="menuLink" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton_Home_Click"><div class="menuIcon">Home</div></asp:LinkButton>

$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#newHome').click(function (e) {
            <%=Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(LinkButton_Home, String.Empty)%>                
        });
    });
```

Comment: That does not trigger the onClick

Comment: I see, try with String.Empty as the second argument, answer updated.

Comment: Yup! That works. Thanks a lot. Been trying so hard to solve it.